# how to check a ssh key is copied to remote server by script

Tags: shell, ssh

I want use a script like below to check if ssh key in my host is copied to remote server:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "ls >/dev/null </dev/null"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ;then
  echo "key copied to remote server"
else
  echo "key not copied to remote server"
fi
```

but it always pending on password input in some case,

```
user@server's password:
```

if there any way to terminate this session and return error immediately?

Comment: If you want to use password during ssh you can use `sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `-o PubkeyAuthentication=yes` and `-o PasswordAuthentication=no` to the ssh command in your script

Comment: It would be great if you could: a) advise why he did not get the right result, and b) show what result should happen when using this switch-option.

Comment: at the time this question was answered, often ssh default config was IMHO misconfigured that if PublicKeyAuthentication failed then it would fall back to password.  By explictly adding these options client side it will fail instead of doing a fallback